# Embed Shiny App in WordPress

Tags: html, r, wordpress, shiny

Anyone had any experience with embedding Shiny applications in WordPress. An example of the embed code I was trying to use with WordPress html editor is found [here](http://stla.github.io/stlapblog/posts/rsm3Dshiny.html).

WordPress visual editor shows the usable shiny application, but if the blog post is previewed or published, it just shows a link to the shinyio server.

If anyone has any experience with using shiny on WordPress, that'd be great. Also open to other free blog suggestions that definitely do work with shiny.

Comment: `iframe` is pretty much the only choice. You need to use the source editor (not the visual editor) to insert the iframe code.

Comment: @XiongbingJin post as answer please.