# Embed Shiny Application in WordPress

Tags: html, r, wordpress, shiny

I have the same question as asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37326131/embed-shiny-app-in-wordpress), but I cannot comment (so new question):
I want to embed a shiny app in a wordpress site. when I add 
`<iframe src="myurl"</iframe>` in the html-editor, I can see the linked website when I switch to the visual editor. but when I update, I see only the link on the website. any idea what the problem is?

Comment: *"as is asket here"* ... where?

Comment: Is this a WordPress.com site or WordPress.org?

Comment: @David.J: it is a wordpress.com site. link to same question in stackoverflow added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress.com does not allow this, ref: https://en.support.wordpress.com/code/

> Flash and other types of embed that use; frame, iframe, form, input, object, textarea are not allowed in WordPress.com posts, pages, or text widgets on the Premium Plan and below.

Comment: To expand on that, when you would host your own Wordpress site (on your own domain) it _would_ work.

Comment: WordPress.org would allow you to do this. You can also enable this on your site by upgrading your package to the Business Plan. From the page: "If you would like to add any code that you want, the WordPress.com Business Plan now offers that option. Click here for more information on adding code on the Business Plan." Ref: https://en.support.wordpress.com/code/

Comment: @Bram Vanroy: meaning that if I would stay at wordpress.com, but use my own domain (withouth business plan), it would work?

Comment: @DanieleS. Unlikely. From what I read, they remove the tags such as `iframe` when you submit the post/page on their server-side. You'd have to host your own Wordpress website to make sure that you are in control of what is filtered and what is not.

Comment: From the link, you can use your own domain and upgrade to the Business plan and you can then use the iFrame code without issue. Please have a read: https://en.support.wordpress.com/code/

Comment: But that's a €300/year plan. Finding your own host will likely be (a lot) cheaper.

Comment: Agreed. The cost basis is up for the OP's discretion.